# Xen on bare metal, multiple guest OSes — is 3D acceleration on each OS possible?

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have a desktop PC (Athlon 64, 2 cores).

I want:

- to run Windows (Vista most likely) with full 3D support for video games and Youtube,
- to also run Debian GNU/Linux with 3D support for work,
- maybe other OSes as well.

I don't think my CPU supports VT-x, but it should have AMD-V.  So the question is: can all of this be done with Xen (Xen on bare metal, all OSes as guests) with 3D working everywhere?

Comment: I don't think you'd get decent performance out of Hackintosh running Parallels. Hackintosh questions are off topic for Super User.

Comment: Ok, edited for more generality

Comment: Looks good, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's becoming possible to share a GPU between guest OSes on modern Intel Platforms (Haswell and later) using XenGT (Intel GVT-g).

For AMD, as I understand [this](http://www.amd.com/en-us/solutions/professional/virtualization), it's possible only for a limited number of dedicated server GPUs.

Comment: The Intel CPUs need integrated Iris pro for it to work though.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Could you please prove that Iris Pro is needed? I see only the statement "support starting from 4th Generation Intel Core processors with Intel Graphics processors" ([source](https://01.org/igvt-g)). Therefore, as I understand it, other integrated GPUs (HD and Iris) should be supported also.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, it s possible, but there are some caveats.  In order to have each guest have 3D acceleration, you'll need to pass through a graphics card of some sort to each guest.  This means that you either have to have GPU capable of being presented to multiple guests, a GPU for each guest, or only run as many guests concurrently as you have GPUs to support it.  The GPUs that support multiple guests are generally pretty expensive - the nVidia Tesla series is one of them, and I believe starts around $1000 USD.  Other, less expensive GPUs can also be used, but generally only support a single guest, and it is hit-or-miss as to whether they work with Xen.